# HTML5 webapp design: app cache

Tags: html, html5-apps

I'm developing a mobile web app, and I'd like to take advantage of the new HMTL5 caching features. The app consists in a photo manager: the user can create albums, store photos, edit pictures and data, and so on. I use the jQuery Mobile framework and all data is stored client-side (webstorage) apart from images, which are uploaded to the server.

I have not added the HTML5 caching yet, but I rely on the normal browser caching for images, and when the user edits an image and this is uploaded to the server, I change the querystring attached to the image request so I get the updated version (a trick I came to know here on stackoverflow).

I'd like to use HTML5 caching for everything, except for images, since this trick works like a charm, but I understand that once I add HMTL5 caching, every resource is:

- either cached and not updated until a new manifest is detected / I do it programmatically (and I can't choose which resource to update) (CACHE section)
- or not cached at all and reloaded everytime (NETWORK section)

Is there a way to have the cake and eat it too? :-)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every resource is cached once you start caching, depends on what is specified in your manifest file, so you could try to take out from the manifest the image urls you do not want to get cached.

Comment: Hi Santiago, thanks for replying. Actually I'd like images to be cached, but with the same process as the normal caching, so that I can download an image again when user edits it. Anyway I'll try you solution.

Comment: Hi Ale, As far as I know the specified urls in the manifest will be hard cached and the urls are not there will be cached as it normally does with any webpage.